# Loop to copy paste row into column, perform calculations and store results

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to write a macro that will copy a range (6 different numbers in cells `B11:G11` in cells `T11:T16`, then perform some computations using these cells `T11:T16` in a table next to it which results are displayed in another table "results" in cells `AJ11:AP47`. That's simulation #1. Next, I'd like to move to the next row and copy `B12:G12` into `T11:T16` again in order to run the same computations with a different input range and stored the results in the "results" table.

I've tried to record the macro and mixed with other pieces of code I found here but it's still not working.

```
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'

    Range("B11:G11").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("T11").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True

    Range("B12:G12").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("T11").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True

    Range("B13:G13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("T11").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Thanks a lot for your help or pieces of advice!

Comment: Could you be more specific about what's "not working"?  Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused at to what you want to achieve with your VBA, is it simply changing the values in the range T11:T16 or do you need it to run the calculations in your "Results" table and save them somewhere?

If you're switching between data sources I might suggest doing something like this and attaching each macro to a toggle button;

```
Sub sim1()
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Integer
r = 11 'row of data to move
i = 12 'starting row of data destination
c = 2 'starting column of data to move
t = 20 'destination column number
    Do While c <= 7
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, t).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, c).Value
        c = c + 1
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Sub sim2()
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Integer
r = 12 'row of data to move
i = 12 'starting row of data destination
c = 2 'starting column of data to move
t = 20 'destination column number
    Do While c <= 7
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, t).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(12, c).Value
        c = c + 1
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Marc. Thanks for the quick reply. I'm running some computations based on the inputs in T11:T16 which change each time I'm going down a row in my "data" table. I'd like to copy paste the 1st row from my "data" table in the 1st column of the "computations" table which populate another table called the "results" table. I then extract 1 particular row from the "results" table and store it in another table, called "report" table. Then I move on to the 2nd row of the "data" table still using the 1st column of the "computations" table (T11:T16) and etc. Hope this clarifies a bit.